# Teseract training in android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

Recently, I've succeeded in creating a simple OCR android app. However, the problem is that the numbers are not read accurately. I've googled on training data but I find it hard to understand.

I want to know how will I be able to make a trained data for android in windows ? Is there a simple way to improve the accuracy for reading digits from a image ? What exactly is a traineddata ? Sorry for a novice question, but I can't clearly grasp it.

Comment: You can check this tool: https://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer or search for jTessBoxEdit

Comment: I've been using that right now, but the problem is that the tool crashes after I set the tif file and run.

Comment: Well, I don't know, but when I used this tool, it worked well. I think you should post a question on this official tesseract group for dev:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tesseract-dev